# How do I setup an .htaccess file to exclude a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have a website setup in the following way:

- `example.com` is the root domain
- The `.htaccess` file redirects all requests to the root URL to `blog.example.com`

This is because the `blog` subdomain is a mirror of the main domain and is what will be used moving forward.

The problem is that there's a second domain: `product.com` that is pointing to `example.com/product`.

As the `.htaccess` file is configured, *all* incoming requests are mapped to `blog.example.com`.

This means that going to `product.com` will result in `blog.example.com/product` in which the ideal scenario is to have `example.com/product` and all other incoming requests be redirected to `blog.example.com`.

A copy of my `.htaccess` file is below:

```
# Block access to the root site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)$ [NC]

# Whitelist specific areas of the root site
# e.g category slugs or page slugs you want to remain viewable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/blog.* [NC]

# Set like-to-like redirect URL for anything not whitelisted
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog\.example\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

How can I construct my rules in the following way:

- `product.com` redirects to `example.com/product`
- `example.com` redirects to `blog.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect anything that is different than /blog and /product to blog.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/product.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```